# Android dropshadow on custom vector

Tags: android, svg, vector

I would like to be able to add a dropshadow to vectors that I have in my drawables folder.  Currently, when I import the svg which has a dropshadow into Android Studio, the conversion to xml removes the dropshadow.

**How would I go about creating a dropshadow for a vector graphic in Android Studio?**

This is an example image of the vector I'm trying to add dropshadow to.[image]

Comment: you have to draw it by yourself, make a custom `Drawable` class and do the drawing inside `draw` method, first draw the shadow then original `Drawable`

Comment: That sounds like the worst.  I think I'll just use pngs with different resolutions if it comes down to it.

Comment: worst?  what do you mean?

Comment: Sounds like more work than it is worth, but I'll have to look into it

Comment: whats so hard in [this](http://pastebin.com/4jzE5PHs) simple implementation?

Comment: of course you can do that more realistic and instead of flat shadows you can use `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` to blur the edges, *BTW* if you want to use shadow pngs with different resolutions why do you want to use vectors at all?

Comment: Appreciate your feedback on this topic since I'm not as familiar with this area of Android. This sounds like a good solution for something I could make reusable.  I have the ability to export the image as an svg or as pngs with different densities.  I would prefer vectors, but pngs wouldn't be a problem to get.

Answer (score 6):

You can create shadow without blur of edges:
* open "drawable xml" file;
* add before (for each path) a group with translations for shadow (depends of vector resolutions) and fill it by dark transparent color, for example:

```
  <group
      android:translateX="150"
      android:translateY="150"
      >
    <path
        android:pathData="..."
        android:fillColor="#40000000"
        />
  </group>
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample code, this snippet is a bit confusing. I am confused about where to add this. Could you please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Nice, it works.
Example for my asset: https://gist.github.com/ktiniatros/c9969ff3bfef9015b09e197fe3e2a633
I added the group above the original path.
Note that this is a small icon (24x24) so I use a bit of translation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following simple way: you need to duplicate the path tag with the same pathData and add the necessary parameters to it(strokeWidth, strokeColor, strokeLineJoin, strokeLineCap).

For a smoother shadow transition, you can duplicate the path tag several times with a larger strokeWidth. The order of the tags is also important. example code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:viewportWidth="20"
    android:viewportHeight="20">

<path
    android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:strokeColor="#FFEB3B"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round" />
<path
    android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z"
    android:strokeWidth=".5"
    android:strokeColor="#2196F3"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z"/></vector>
```

[vector in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIkyZ.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you have an svg editor tool like sketch, I would add the shadow through that and save the svg. Then use the following tool to convert it to an android drawable.
http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

Then finally either download the xml file to your drawable folder or select and copy the content and manually create a new drawable resource in your project and copy the  content into it. Easy peasy :). Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: when converting to .xml shadow from Sketch is not passed. You get the image vectors without a shadow

Comment: That link to the tool doesn't do much. It stripped out the colors for me.